# Wiremock refused to connect while debugging

Tags: java, junit5, wiremock

I have a problem with connecting to my wiremock server that is started from a test. When I put a breakpoint after the wiremock server is started, and I use my browser to go to the specified url, it states: localhost refused to connect.
I have downgraded the test to the most basic version.

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlEqualTo;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MyTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(options().bindAddress("127.0.0.1").port(6001));
    server.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/file"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .withBody("Hello world")));
    server.start();
    assertTrue(server.isRunning());
    System.out.println("I put a breakpoint on this line");
}
}
```

I have tried different options with @WireMockTest as well (and tried about every tutorial I could find), with the same result.
When I inspect the WireMockServer object in debug mode, it shows: `server.httpServer.jettyServer = Server@429064e8{STARTED}[9.4.49.v20220914]`

So at least it looks like the server is started. Any ideas?

Btw: When I run wiremock standalone on the same port, it can be accessed just fine.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you've got an "application/json" header but the content "Hello world" is not valid JSON.

Comment: I just noticed and fixed that, but that was indeed not the issue

Comment: Are sure you use correct port in browser ? I don't see port config in code sample. Expected http://localhost:8080/file. Also change log level to debug to see details when WireMock started, of errors presence in there.

Comment: scroll a bit to the right ;) It was running on 6001 in my example, but I tried different ports as well. There were no errors in the log either, as the server was running just fine but the debug mode made it unaccessible. See my answer below

Comment: Another thing confuses me, that if you run server in debug mode, execution is stopped in current thread in which test is executed and i am not sure if server is using own allocated thread pool. You should use actual junit5 extension which will initialize WireMock before execution of test method. This will ensure that server is up and running when test method is called.

Comment: I advice you to use extension which will ensure initializing server before test method is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further investigation, it turns out the debug mode seems to be the problem. When I replace my breakpoint with an indefinite Thread.sleep(), I was able to access the Wiremock server just fine.

I got the idea from an issue reported to WireMock.Net, a C# project that mimics the Java version WireMock:
https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues/510

As k314159 pointed out in the comments, the debugger suspends ALL threads of the test, including the one started by WireMock. To avoid this (in IntelliJ at least) you can edit the breakpoint by right-clicking it, and stating that only the current Thread should be suspended.[image]

Comment: That's not surprising. WireMockServer.start() starts running in a separate thread, which is suspended by the debugger while you're at the breakpoint. While the WireMockServer thread is suspended, it can't serve your HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was indeed the issue. I updated the answer to work around that as well.

Comment: Wow Thanks this answer saved me, but isn't any other work around for this problem? I really need to debug a thread which is not the current thread